# What's the differences between ifdown and "ip link set .. .down"?

Tags: linux, rhel, network-interface, oracle-linux

I did some testing below. It seems `ifdown ens32` didn't bring the interface down. And `ip link` still show `UP`. Only `ip link set ens32 down` brings the interface down. So what's the problem here? Why ifdown can't bring down the interface?

```
root:[~]# cat /etc/*release*
Oracle Linux Server release 7.6
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6"
ID="ol"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.6"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:6:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
Oracle Linux Server release 7.6
cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:6:server
root:[~]# 
root:[~]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:31:a8:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:33:cf:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:33:cf:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root:[~]# ifdown ens32
Device 'ens32' successfully disconnected.
root:[~]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:31:a8:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:33:cf:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:33:cf:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root:[~]# ip link set ens32 down
root:[~]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:31:a8:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:33:cf:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:33:cf:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root:[~]#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true that there's no difference.

`ifup` and `ifdown` read `/etc/network/interfaces`, and on top of bringing the interfaces up and down, they execute lots of scripts also in `/etc/network`, which provides hooks for various things (like DHCP).

On the other hand, `ip link ...` (new variant) and `ifconfig ... up/down` (old variant) set the state of the interface directly, not doing any of the additional actions that may be necessary if an interface goes up and down.

So if `ifdown` doesn't work, your system is probably not configured to use the classic `/etc/network/interfaces` system (for example, because it uses `systemd`, which does everything differently), or there's an error somewhere in some script that's excute first, or possibly some other reason.

Comment: Mostly correct, except this is Oracle Linux, which is a RHEL clone, so instead of /etc/network/ its files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/. /etc/network/interfaces is a Debianism.

Comment: Also, depending on whether NM_CONTROLLED=yes or not, ifup/ifdown will use NetworkManager to bring up/down interfaces, which has a whole collection of additional actions it’ll perform. NetworkManager is enabled by default on el7.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between the new `ip` commands (the new way to do things) and the old ones - there used to be `ipconfig`, `netstat`, `arp` and `route`.  See here for a comparison:

https://p5r.uk/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison.html

https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-vs-ip-command-comparing-network-configuration/

However, `ifup` and `ifdown` are part of network scripts doing more than each single command listed above.  Perhaps your network is managed by wicked or a different network manager.  Try

```
rpm -qf `/sbin/ifdown`
```

to see whether perhaps `ifdown` is part of some network management package - this varies across distributions.

So maybe you need to change the way your network is managed by your network config tool.

Comment: Does iprouter2 include netstat functionality

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 The replacement for `netstat` in the new `ip` System is called `ss`.

Comment: Note that this is true for `ifconfig` vs. `ip`, but not for `ifup` and `ifdown`.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks, I corrected by mistake!