# Options up or down in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ not working with static method

Tags: debian, networking, routing

I have the following network (all machines are Debian GNU/Linux 10 Buster):

```
+----+             +--------+                    +--------+             +----+
|.1.x| <-->   .1.1 |ROUTER-A| .101.1 <--> .101.2 |ROUTER-B|   .2.1 <--> |.2.x|
+----+      enp0s8 +--------+ enp0s9      enp0s9 +--------+ enp0s8      +----+
```

I am trying to make machines in the `.1.x` network able to communicate with the machines in the `.2.x` network.

According to [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configuring-static-routes-in-debian-or-red-hat-linux-systems.html) or [this one](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration), we can add `up` commands inside our interface files. So I tried it.

```
/etc/network/
             interfaces
             interfaces.d/
                          enp0s3-nat
                          enp0s8-intnet-1
                          enp0s9-intnet-101
                          loopback
```

Inside `enp0s9-intnet-101`:

```
allow-hotplug enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet static
  address 192.168.101.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.101.1
  network 192.168.101.0

  up ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.101.2
```

But it does not work. Out of curiosity, I tried `up echo "hello world" > /tmp/hello-test`, and it does not work either.

If I replace my `static` method by a `manual` one:

```
allow-hotplug enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet manual
  up ip address add 192.168.101.1/24 dev enp0s9
  up ip route   add 192.168.2.0/24   via 192.168.101.2
```

It works on reboot, but if I "down-and-up" my interface with `ip link set enp0s9 down` then `ip link set enp0s9 up`, the route is no longer available.

So my questions:

- Is it possible or not to use `up` commands in a `static` method?
- Why, with my `manual` method, the route is not created with `ip link set enp0s9 up`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to [this ticket](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=783986#10):

> The post-up lines are executed for static ipv6 interfaces, but not if
>   something went wrong while configuring the interface.

The same applies for ipv4 interfaces. So I went ahead, and removed one by one the lines between `iface enp0s9 inet static` and `up ip route add ...` until it worked; and the culprit was `gateway 192.168.101.1`. The following works as expected:

```
allow-hotplug enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet static
  address 192.168.101.1/24
  up ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.101.2
```

I also removed the `netmask` option (deprecated) and the `network` one (not even mentioned in the manpages). Instead, I used the `address` option with the `dotted quad/netmask` syntax.

My guess is that the `gateway` cannot be the same IP address than `address`.

As to why "the route is not created with `ip link set enp0s9 up`", it is correctly created when using `ifup enp0s9` instead, which is a higher level command that does way more than `ip link set ... up` (see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534879/247149) for additional information).